# Backbonejs Model.url required?

Tags: rest, backbone.js, marionette

I have an example setup to show my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/5xo4yzw2/1/

```
var root = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function(){
        return this.get('url') || root + "/posts/" + this.get('id')
    }
});

var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post,
    url: root + "/posts"
});


var posts = new Posts();
posts.fetch();
console.log("Call to collection fetch works")

var post = new Post({id: 1});
post.fetch();
console.log("Call to collection fetch works")
```

This example works, that is, both of the console.logs are executed without an exception being raised by `.fetch()`. It was my understanding, however, from both http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url and the book I am reading, that once I specify `"/posts"` as the collection url, the model url should be automatically resolved to `[collection.url]/[id]`, though that is not the case. If I do not provide the url function in the model, an exception is raises upon fetching, stating the th url parameter must be provided.

Have i misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added your *post* model to your collection, in order for a model to use the collections URL it must be part of that collection.

For example

```
var post = new Post({id: 1});
posts.add(post);
post.fetch();
console.log("Call to collection fetch works")
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xo4yzw2/2/)

As [@Artem Baranovskii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5179195/artem-baranovskii) pointed out, If you want to use a model outside a collection you should be using the urlRoot property. From the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot)

> Specify a urlRoot if you're using a model outside of a collection, to
>   enable the default url function to generate URLs based on the model
>   id. "[urlRoot]/id" Normally, you won't need to define this. Note that
>   urlRoot may also be a function.

Comment: So, If one model is all i need, I need an empty collection that I can add it to, and then fetch? I suppose that makes sense, although not intuitive with what I'm coming from

Comment: No, as @Artem pointed out in his answer you can use the urlroot property for that.

Comment: Just to be sure: The collection refers to an endpoint of my restful service, which returns an array of objects (/posts). The model is the representation of a single object within that collection. I sometimes want to retrieve the entire collection, and I sometimes want to retrieve just one of the objects. Should I still use urlRoot in that case? That seems odd to me

Comment: If that context changes within your application then I would probably add the model to the collection and not use the urlRoot, and when you just want that single mode call its fetch. I think using the urlRoot is more for cases where the model doesn't conceptually belong to a collection.

Comment: That's what I thought ;) Just needed confirmation. Thanks for your time. You've been most helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a model outside of the collection you could use [urlRoot](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) like the following:

```
var root = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

var Posts = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: function () {
       return this.get('url') || (root + "/posts/" + this.get('id'))
   }
});

var posts = new Posts();
posts.fetch();

console.log("Call to collection fetch works")
```

When you execute `fetch` the model tries to get url by the several approaches [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L691)